# CakePHP: How to capture and upload a photo without tripping a black-hole from the security component?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, webcam

My intent is to create a "take a picture of yourself" feature on a website I'm creating.  The hope is to capture a photo via the webcam and assign it to the user.

I assume (perhaps incorrectly):

1. I need to use jquery to capture the image.
2. I should upload the image via the user registration form, and reference it's filename via the db and a known path.

Where I'm stuck:

How do I upload an image once captured by jquery?  I'm assume there are some jquery scripts I can grab to take the photo... but how do I get the photo properly uploaded without getting blackholed by the security component?

The answers here might be stupid obvious, but I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: The answer to your first question is dependent on what you're using to create the image, and is possibly answered in whatever FAQ comes with it.  As for the second, you can disable the Security component's checks, which you will need to do if you end up having to submit data via ajax.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-security-component-for-specific-actions

Comment: @Kai- thanks for weighing in.  In regards to the first, this is a little bit of an ambiguous answer, but perhaps it was an ambiguous question.  My question was with reference to the CakePHP framework... how does one go about an upload with in it?  Perhaps a Base64 blob?  Or is there a way to capture a webcam image and submit that image as a file?  In answer to your second point, let's say I don't want to disable security (which is the obvious solution, ha ha - kind of like if I had asked "How do I not get shocked changing an outlet" and you replied "Don't change an outlet," ha ha)?

Comment: Further clarification on that first point: I'd rather work out the CakePHP side and find the appropriate jquery app than the other way around.  So what is the best way to approach this for Cake?

Comment: In more detail on the second point, when I say disable the security component, it's because I don't believe there's any way to get the security checks to pass if you're submitting data via ajax, and therefore you have to just disable it.  Or at least, that's what I've seen people write in multiple places, such as http://whatswhat.no/development/framework/cakephp-2/465-making-a-jquery-ajax-call-with-security-component-activated-in-cakephp-2, and it is also alluded to in the cookbook (it specifically mentions ajax  when it tells you how to disable it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a normal file field that is populated by jquery, you will need to do something like this:

```
$this->Form->unlockField('upload_image'); // Set 'upload_image' to the name of your field
```

([Cookbook reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent%3a%3a%24unlockedFields))

I use this method inside a formHelper that I created to make uploading images easy, it works well.

Edit: incidentally, if using an iPhone or iPad, those devices support taking a picture with the webcam and populating a normal file upload field.  I've used an iPhone to upload a webcam picture (taken after the "browse" button is pressed) and it worked fine.

Comment: Great start, that definitely gets me started.  Now if I can just figure out how to do the same with computers.